# Consuming ArcGIS Online services from ArcGIS Desktop 10.0?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-online

I work at a county government and was at one of our municipalities recently.
I was planning to show them how to consume our cached tile service from our most recent flyover that I have hosted on AGOL. I brought up AGOL from the ArcMap menu and searched for the relative tags. It showed my service in the results, but nothing happened when I clicked the "Add" option.  The tile service is shared to everyone so no sign in was necessary.

I did notice that they're still running ArcGIS 10.0.  Does anyone know if there is an issue with 10.0 not being able to consume certain services? I'm just trying to troubleshoot why it wasn't working for them. Their computer has Internet access.

Comment: Have you installed 10 Service packs? (I assume there are 4 service packs for 10)

Comment: That's a good question.  I kind of doubt they did.  I'm expecting to see someone from their office in the next day or 2 so I'll ask him when I see him.
For the record, we're running 10.3.1 desktop and AGOL

Comment: There were actually five service packs to ArcGIS 10.0, the last of which was issued 42 months ago. There really is no reason not to be current on 10.0 service packs. It still might not help, since 3.5 years is more than a generation of technology, and making clients future-compatible is usually a feature of science fiction, but running SP5 would be a good first step.

Comment: What are the "certain services" that you cannot consume?  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to provide any clarifications that others request via comments.

Comment: Cached tile service.  It's already in the question.